# Crontab not running PHP scripts properly

Tags: php, cron

I have the following commands set in my crontab

```
0 * * * * root cd /home/domain/public_html/webcrawler && php cron1.php
40 * * * * root cd /home/domain/public_html/webcrawler && php cron2.php
```

The thing is they are not running. Is there any noticeable errors in the commands I have set? The php scripts run fine when run from ssh, or loaded in the browser. I have tried with and without root at the start.

Comment: Try using the full path to PHP. The PHP executable might not be in the path for the user that cron is running under.

Comment: Could you try to absolute path reference PHP? /usr/bin/php cron1.php

Comment: never thought about it, but a simple `cd /some/path/other/than/current && ls` displays the file listing of my *current* folder, so in essense you're calling the php script from the default user directory

Comment: Yeah that's the most common problem I've run into with my PHP CRON scripts. Also make sure in your PHP file everything is referenced with absolute path as well. Note* in regards to @Machavity 's answer, PHP may be in a different location on your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call PHP cron jobs with the full path (note, your PHP may be in a different location)

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php
```

Comment: Typically the `cd` will change your directory. When used in conjunction with `&&` the following command will be run from the `cd`'d directory.

Comment: Don't forgot to reference the path for PHP as well!! /usr/bin/php :)

Answer (score 2):

Change out the `&&` with `;` to read like

```
0 * * * * root cd /home/domain/public_html/webcrawler; php cron1.php
```

or execute it from the absolute path

```
0 * * * * root php /home/domain/public_html/webcrawler/cron1.php
```

When using the absolute path you can force your cron script's current working directory by performing

```
chdir(__DIR__); //or chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```

You can also add the PHP shebang to the top of you cron.php file (your php binary may have a different path)

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Then you can execute the script without needing to reference the php binary location using

```
0 * * * * root /home/domain/public_html/webcrawler/cron1.php
```